# suspend & shut down issues (possibly related to GPU driver)

Tags: 16.04, suspend, shutdown, gpu, hybrid-graphics

I apologize in advance for not providing a lot of technical info but only a description of the problem.

Since I updated Ubuntu to version 16.04 a couple of months ago I've had a problem with the suspend mode. Namely, when I'd close the lid or simply suspend the laptop I wouldn't be able to wake it up, there would simply be some message on the screen saying that the GPU couldn't start. This is fairly common (judging from the number of such questions on the web), but none of the proposed solutions worked for me.

I've solved the problem recently, and quite trivially, by simply switching off my nVidia GPU in the NVIDIA X Server settings. Note that I could choose between two proprietary and one open driver for the nVidia GPU and no choice works. The only option thus was to use my Intel GPU instead.

Ironically enough a new error appeared now. I can suspend my computer normally, but I cannot turn it off anymore. When I try to restart or switch off it essentially switches everything off but then it gets stuck while showing empty desktop background (no icons or anything else, just the background picture).

Another absurd thing is that while I had suspend problems I also had another problem that was magically resolved by turning to the Intel GPU. When I would start the computer it would not start the screen exactly every other time. E.g. I'd switch the computer off, next time I turn it on it doesn't turn on the screen but after a minute I can hear the Ubuntu welcome sound, I turn it off via switch-off button, I turn it on again and now everything works. Next time I have to repeat the process.
I'm guessing this points to a faulty GPU card? This couldn't have possibly be caused by Ubuntu.

I'm running a dual boot system with Win 7 on another partition. There seemed to be no problems with Win 7 all this time.

I'd be very grateful for any input and I apologize for writing such a long question. Let me know about any further info you may need.

Thanks! Best,

V

Comment: I found a solution to the last problem that I described, the inability to shut down on Intel card.
I've tried again installing nvidia driver via terminal, after which I did apt-get autoremove. This raised some issues while cleaning dkms files, so I also did dmks autoinstall to be sure that I'll be able to boot again. After this I could restart and shut down normally. Note, however, that if I switch to the nVidia card it still 'crashes' if I try to logout for example.